# Low CMOS battery but it's brand new

Tags: boot, motherboard, battery, battery-life, cmos

When booting my old PC it says low CMOS battery so I replaced it with a spare battery which I bought a few years back. Upon booting from power-off state, it still says low CMOS battery.

Is it possible that the new replacement battery has already expired or is there a problem with my mobo?

Comment: You should use a voltmeter (e.g. digital multimeter aka DMM) to test for a weak battery. Also avoid getting skin oils (e.g. fingerprints) on the battery and the battery holder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, the new battery may have been faulty. It is also yes, the motherboard could be faulty.. We simply can't asnwer this question!

The only way to know is for you to buy a brand new battery. Test it. You will then have your answer.

Also, as BigChris mentions in the comments, the battery could easily have lost charge through self-dischage. [More info on batteries](http://www.batteryeducation.com/2006/04/battery_degrada.html)

Also see [even more info](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries)

Comment: You might also want to add that as the OP was using a battery "bought a few years back" that the battery will have likely lost charge through self-discharge, and potentially causing the symptoms described :)

Comment: Something to be aware of: some battery manufacturers have stopped putting dates on their batteries.  That makes it easy for suppliers to dump old batteries into the marketplace at low prices.  The "new" battery you buy could already be close to expired.  Buy only batteries with dates.  The shelf life is typically 7 to 10 years, so look for batteries with at least 5 years left before expiration.

Comment: *"The only way to know is for you to buy a brand new battery"* -- No that's not the only way.  There are neat devices called voltmeters to test batteries.